# CefSharp WPF and Offscreen perfomance

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

i m trying to suppot an app, that uses cefsharp(v79.1.360).

**There are list of things I need to implement:**

1) ChromiumWebBrowser in WPF (using CefSharp.Wpf minimum example)

2) This browser can go offscreen(with collapsing window or closing it)

3) Work with JavaScriptObjectRepository, and launch some code, that will be do work with web pages(click buttons, change text of elements). Pages may use frameworks, websockets, Http requests and the other stuff 
 web pages usually do.

After pages work is done, i send results to C# by calling Methods of object, i bounded in jsObjectRepository/

**Expectations:**

Offscreen prefomance(time delay) should be as well as With opened window/

**Reality:**

Offscreen perfomance sometimes is really bad, it take time to do work up to 10 seconds(when wpf is only 1-5).

My code:

*Initialization*

```
CefSharpSettings.LegacyJavascriptBindingEnabled = true;
            CefSharpSettings.WcfEnabled = true;

            CefSettings cefSettings = new CefSettings
            {
                LocalesDirPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "locales"),
                Locale = appsettings.CurrentChromeLanguage.ToLocal(),
                AcceptLanguageList = appsettings.CurrentChromeLanguage.ToAcceptList(),
            };


            if (!cefSettings.CefCommandLineArgs.ContainsKey("disable-gpu"))
            {
                cefSettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu", "1");
            }
            if (cefSettings.CefCommandLineArgs.ContainsKey("enable-system-flash"))
            {
                cefSettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Remove("enable-system-flash");
            }
            if (cefSettings.CefCommandLineArgs.ContainsKey("enable-media-stream"))
            {
                cefSettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Remove("enable-media-stream");
            }


            cefSettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-begin-frame-scheduling", "1");
            cefSettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu-vsync", "1");

            cefSettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("mute-audio", "true");
            cefSettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-media-stream", "0");
            cefSettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-3d-apis", "1");
            cefSettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("renderer-process-limit", "10");

            cefSettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("js-flags", "--lite_mode");


            if (!appsettings.IsLoadImage)
            {
                cefSettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-image-loading", "1");
            }
            cefSettings.LogFile = Path.Combine(ClientConfig.ChromeDataPath, "Log.txt");
            cefSettings.LogSeverity = LogSeverity.Error;
            cefSettings.IgnoreCertificateErrors = true;


            cefSettings.SetOffScreenRenderingBestPerformanceArgs();
```

*Browser creating and usage:*

```
ChromiumWebBrowser browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();

//xaml window with <ContentControl> with browser
//need hide means when window is closing, we cancel it, and using Hide()
NewBrowserView view = new NewBrowserView(new ChromeTabViewModel(browser));

view.Closing += BrowserView_Closing;
Browser.FrameLoadStart += _browser_FrameLoadStart;
var options = new BindingOptions { CamelCaseJavascriptNames = false };
browser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register("resultController", this, false, options);


//we can just hide window
void BrowserView_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
            if (_needHide)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                Hide();
            }
}

//on page load
void _browser_FrameLoadStart(object sender, FrameLoadStartEventArgs e) {
  string code = "";
  code += "(async function(){ " +
  "await CefSharp.BindObjectAsync('resultController'); " +
  code += TestJsCode;
  code += " })();";//AddWorker
  e.Frame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync(code, $"about:blank/myCode");
  Consol.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
}

public void OnGoodResult()
{
 Consol.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
}

public void OnBadResult()
{
  Consol.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
}

//then i just go by differnet pages and await results
```

As i mentioned before, when i hide wnd, its taking too long time to print result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really depended on Layouts and other visuals, so i figured this out. I should just set this code, when window is collapsing:

```
GetBrowser().GetHost().WasHidden(false);
```